# HTC Wildfire won't boot

Tags: boot, fastboot, htc-wildfire

My HTC Wildfire will not boot up. When I boot normally with the SD card in, I only get a screen that says "Fastboot" with the options bootloader, reboot, reboot bootloader and power down. It says to use the volume keys to select the option and press the power button to select. Using any of these buttons does nothing.

I then need to take the battery out, and power up while pressing the volume up button. I get an HBoot menu with the options fastboot, recovery, clear storage and simlock. The volume button does not allow me to select anything, but when I press the power button to select fastboot I get a number of messages saying `SD checking load image [xxxx.zip] No image found` This happens too quickly for me to see the name of the files missing.

I am able to connect my phone to a computer using USB, but I can do nothing there also.

Anybody got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Basically something wrong and bad happened and hence your phone is unable to boot.  I am not sure this is the answer, but I am just trying to help as I too faced such problem and was in panic during initial days with Android.

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1622178) XDA site beautifully explains the boot related problems and how you could get over.  Basically you have to reflash the ROM for which you need few USB drivers + flashing tool and original or some other ROM.  Though I am unable to point you to exactly to sites that provide these, I guess you can easily search for it.

TIP: Had if your phone Clockworkmod recovery, things will be bit easy. This is one convincing reason, I made up my mind to root and install CWM recovery as a first step on all my devices.

Answer (score 0):

Before facing problems, make some backups : *Nandroid* for full and *Titanium* for partial ones.

When problems occurs, use restore from this backups.